# terminal after installing R using homebrew

Tags: r, homebrew

After installing R using homebrew on mac following the instructions from here :  https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/installing-R-windows-mac-ubuntu . When I open the terminal I get these :

```
-bash: /Users/myname/.bash_profile: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `category="LC_ALL",'
-bash: /Users/myname/.bash_profile: line 27: `Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale = "en_US.UTF-8")'
```

so how could I fix/get rid of these from appearing on the terminal .

I think this has something to do with :

```
$ echo "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the line 27 of your `.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 0):

The [instructions that you link to](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/installing-R-windows-mac-ubuntu) say to do this in Step 3 to add stuff to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
echo 'Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale = "en_US.UTF-8")' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

I think that is wrong. That is R code, not bash code, so it shouldn't go in `~/.bash_profile`. It should go in `~/.Rprofile` instead.

Remove line 27 (the one that says `Sys.setlocale(...)`) from your `~/.bash_profile` and add it to your `~/.Rprofile` file instead.

And then send DataCamp an email telling them that their R installation instructions have a significant error in them.

Comment: While you're emailing Datacamp, you could also inquire about this: https://noamross.github.io/datacamp-sexual-assault/